# Execute shell script multiple commands in one line using Process Builder in Java (Unix)

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have a shell script that I would like to execute from java.

```
sudo su - username -c "ssh -t remote_hostname df -k"
```

This shell script works fine when you ran from the command prompt. 
However when I used process builder it will not return anything. If I do the following:
sudo su - username -c ssh -t remote_hostname;df -k

then the command is running on my local machine not on the remote machine.

Appreciated any feedback.

---

java code

```
Process p;

ExecutorService es = null;
try {

p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(test1.sh);

StreamGobbler sg = new StreamGobbler(p.getInputStream(), System.out::println());

es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

es.submt(sg);

int exitCode = p.waitfor();

assert exitCode == 0;

es.shutdown();


} catch (....) {
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code? May be worth noting, if you run from eclipse your shell environment won't usually be set

Comment: What machine? Your ssh command doesn't include one, are you sure that command runs from the prompt?

Comment: Updated the content with the java code

Comment: The shel script tst1.sh contains sudo su - username -c "ssh -t remote_hostname df -k"

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.exec(String)` is not a shell, and in particular doesn't parse and handle quotes like a shell. Dupe:
[Why does Runtime.exec(String) work for some but not all commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776546/why-does-runtime-execstring-work-for-some-but-not-all-commands)
[Whitespace in bash path with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425729/whitespace-in-bash-path-with-java)
[Keytool command does not work when invoked with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988220/keytool-command-does-not-work-when-invoked-with-java)

Do something like

```
String[] cmd = { "sudo", "su", "-", "username", "-c", "ssh -t remote_hostname df -k" };
// note the last element is a single Java String that does not _contain_ 
// any quote characters (which would be backslashed in Java source)
... Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) ...
```

Also, you shouldn't need `-t` when remoting `df -k` -- it doesn't do any special output handling. (Although it doesn't hurt, and is nearly free.)

Comment: Thank you so much, the above solution works. I appreciated very much for the answer as I have spent a week trying to figure out why it will not work in Java.

Comment: Yes Dave you are right... I removed my response because was a totally wrong content... Anyway this topic moved some interest in me so i started writing some code... I think that this side of java can be improved writing some good library! Tonight I started writing a library to execute entire scripts from java code using the exec() method. If you are interested contributing here's the github link https://github.com/robertomanfreda/java_bash_executor . The workaround i used is: read a file line after line, encode the content in base64 and execute the encoded content on /bin/bash using base64 :)